# Header using Itext

Tags: html, pdf, itext

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(headerContent,headerFont) ,document.right() - 300, document.top() + 5, 0);
```

I have this line of code.For A4 papersize I get the header at the center of the page but for A3,A2,A1 I get it to the left of the page.What should I do so that I get it to the center of the page for all papersize(A4,A3,A2,A1).

Comment: How did you come to use `document.right() - 300` as reference x coordinate? The 300 introduces format dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `(document.left() + document.right()) / 2` for the `x` value.
As for the `y` value, you should use `document.top() - (headerFont.getSize() * 1.5f)`. As far as I know `document.top() + 5` results in adding text in the invisible area above the actual page.